# change the color of each pivot item in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to assign the different colors to each pivot item of pivot control of windows 8.

Red color for all, green for assigned. How do i achieve it??

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0B345A">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="MY TASKS">
        <!--Pivot item one-->            
        <phone:PivotItem  Header="all">                           
            <Grid>                    
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <StackPanel Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="0">

                    <TextBlock Text="Due Today 12:00PM" Foreground="#FF4472A2"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                       <TextBlock Text="Sales On-Boarding" Foreground="#FFB7BEC6"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Due 9/25/13" Foreground="#FF4472A2"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>               
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="assigned">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="overdue">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It seems like people aren't grasping your question fully. Perhaps you could include a screenshot with some arrows pointing out exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0B345A">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="MY TASKS">
            <!--Pivot item one-->            
            <phone:PivotItem>    
 <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                        <Grid  Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock Name="allRecords" Text="all"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>                       
                <Grid>                    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <StackPanel Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="0">

                        <TextBlock Text="Due Today 12:00PM" Foreground="#FF4472A2"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                           <TextBlock Text="Sales On-Boarding" Foreground="#FFB7BEC6"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Due 9/25/13" Foreground="#FF4472A2"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>               
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem>
<controls:PivotItem.Header>
                        <Grid Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock Name="assignedRecords" Text="assigned"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>  
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <!--Pivot item three-->
            <phone:PivotItem>
<controls:PivotItem.Header>
                        <Grid Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock Name="overdueRecords" Text="overdue"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>  
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: background property is adding color on full control, i just need to change the header color. means i want to change the color of all header

Comment: Try this one :-  <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                        <Grid Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock  Text="all" />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>

Answer (score 0):

Simply add attribute `Background="your preferred color"` to each `phone:PivotItem`element.

Comment: background property is adding color on full control, i just need to change the header color. means i want to change the color of all header